# Shimano SL-7700 (nine speed) down tube shifters. Index only?

Tags: downtube-shifter

I'm considering buying these. There is confusion about whether the RH (RD) shifter can be switched between index and friction. Dealers and users give conflicting or unclear information. They WERE originally switchable, and there hasn't been a change in product number. The Shimano docs are ambiguous, because some of them are also for the 10 speed, which isn't switchable.

Does anybody have any of these (especially if bought recently) to comment.

Thanks.

Comment: ooh pretty. I can't even guess, but you could order from a supplier who states explicitly that they _are_ switchable, then you have grounds to return them if they are not switchable, above and beyond any default distance-selling buyer protection. Or have the LBS do it

Comment: The pictures you get in a web-search on SL-7700 all show the RH shifter with the switching 'handle', in photos as well as in diagrams.